# Making a custom logger in Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, ruby-on-rails-6

I am working on a project in **Rails 6** and my manager has asked me to implement a custom logger which should track all kinds of activities occurred in our Application. I am working in Rails 6, and I want this logger to be global i.e **I should be able to call it from anywhere in my program**, I should be able to customise the way the logged messaged is formatted,what I want the log message to look like is

> User ID,Time
>
> > the logged message

Can someone please help me regarding this ?, I am a beginner in Ruby on Rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to create your own `.rb` module or class in the `app/lib` folder. Then, you can simply create and write to a log file with something like this:

```
module MyLogger
    def self.log_something
        log = Logger.new('log/mylog.log')
        log.error StandardError.new("some error message")
        log.info("some  informational message") 
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Rails has it's own customization, subclassing the vanilla Ruby `Logger`.

You could probably start looking at that one for inspiration:
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v6.0.0/activesupport/lib/active_support/logger.rb

For more specifics, you'd need to explain better what you'd like to do. For example, do you need to keep the same interface as the Ruby built-in logger class?